# to_param only behaves properly in some controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, scope, controller, acts-as-taggable-on

Per [this guide](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732), I'm using `to_param` to create friendly URLs for my objects. I have a `Tag` object from the `acts_as_taggable_on` gem which uses `to_param` to create URLs with the tag's name instead of its ID:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    name
  end

  def self.find_by_param(input)
    find_by_name(input)
  end
end
```

Now, in a few places in my app i'm linking to the page for this tag which displays all the associated objects. On my homepage, under the `Static` controller (and in other controllers), linking to a `Tag` object behaves properly:

`_tag_item.html.erb`:

```
<span class="tag"><%= link_to "##{tag_item}", tag_path(tag_item) %></span>
```

correctly produces:

```
<span class="tag"><a href="/tags/gandalf">#gandalf</a></span>
```

**Note how the href points to the friendly URL, rather than using an ID, as by default.**

However, in the `Tag` controller itself, on the Tags' `index` page, which lists all the tags in the app, this behavior does not behave properly.

`views/tags/index.html.erb`:

```
<% @tags.each do |tag| %>
    <div class="tag-box">
       <%= link_to tag, tag_path(tag) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

incorrectly produces:

```
<a href="/tags/2">gandalf</a>
```

and i have no idea why.

Answer (score -1):

In `controllers/tags/index.html.erb` change

```
<%= link_to tag, tag_path(tag) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "##{tag}", tag_path(tag) %>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to add a hashtag to the text of the link. I'm trying to get the `link_to` to properly use the friendly URL that i've specified elsewhere. the point is that `link_to` outputs `/tags/gandalf` in some places and `/tags/1` in others.

Comment: OK my bad. Can you debug the `tag` object within the loop whether it's an instance of `Tag`.

Comment: it is an instance of `ActsAsTaggableOn:Tag`, the gem I am using for tagging.

Comment: In `сonfig/initializers/act_as_taggable_on.rb` add ` `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.class_eval do def to_param name end end `